# animated bar chart with simple jquery and javascript,css

Tags: jquery, css

i have used fushioncharts plugin for bar charts with animation in jquery. but it is required adobe flash player. so can anyone help me to have bar charts using simple jquery,css and js. please send me some links that will be helpful to me. thanks

Comment: try highcharts and sencha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the best lib for you AND for your requierements.

[Raphael.js library](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html)

Comment: http://octathorpeweb.com/blog/2012/03/06/creating-dynamic-bar-graphs-using-raphael-js/